# react: Array is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have an Array that has objects inside that looks like this

```
OrchardSite > Array(16) > 0: {blocks: Array (3), name: "asdasd", code: "R101A"}
                          1: {blocks: Array (7), name: "dasdas", code: "R555"}
```

I have JSX that looks like this

```
<select className="input-field-slider dropdown w-select" onChange={() => this.setOrchard}>
    <option>All Sites</option>
    {orchardSites
        .map((orchardSite, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={orchardSite.code}>
                {orchardSite.code + " " + orchardSite.name}
            </option>
        ))}
```

Every time the user selects an option from the dropdown I have this function that fires..

```
setOrchard = (event) => {
  const orchardId = event.target.value;

  console.log("orchardID", orchardId) // returns selected ID
  console.log("OrchardSite", this.props.metadata.OrchardSites) // returns array
  console.log("testing1", this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt("R1018A")] // undefined
  console.log("testing2", this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)]) // undefined
  console.log("new value", this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)].blocks) // Cannot read property 'blocks' of undefined

   if (orchardId.length > 0) {
      if (!this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)].blocks) 
          this.props.metadata.orchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)].blocks = []
            console.log("SetttingOrchardLocation", this.props.metadata.orchardSites)
            this.setState({ orchardId: orchardId, block: null, area: null, row: null, site: Object.assign({}, this.props.metadata.orchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)]) })
            console.log("Testing OrchardId", this.props.metadata.orchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)])
        // parseInt to get access to the array index, (Maybe I need to .ToString() somewhere?
    }
}
```

Which returns..

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'blocks' of undefined

How can I gain access to this array?

Comment: I think problem come from your `this.props.metadata`, If you're reveive this props from fetch API, or using redux..., At the first render, your props will be empty, so you need to check `this.props.metadata` has value or not(or `this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)]`).

Comment: This line will cause error too: `this.props.metadata.OrchardSites` and then `this.props.metadata.orchardSites`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the typo, it doesn't make a difference...at first render, I have full access to the props, I have a console.log in place

Comment: `console.log(this.props.metadata.OrchardSites)` and `console.log(this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)])` right after your  `console.log("orchardID", orchardId)`, and see what showing

Comment: `console.log("orchardID", orchardId)` returns the selected value `console.log("OrchardSite", this.props.metadata.OrchardSites)` returns the array which looks like the above, `console.log("testing1", this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt("R1018A")])` is undefined, the string is the hard coded id, `console.log(this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)])` is undefined

Comment: So, you should change this line `if(!this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)].blocks)` to `if(this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)] && this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)].blocks)`

Comment: the code executes further, though blocks still remain undefined

Answer (score 0):

If both the orchardSites (in your jsx and your onClick function) are the same, then you want to access the array using the array index (i in jsx) instead of the orchardSite.code.

This is because OrchardSites[orchardSite.code] can be undefined in certain cases but OrchardSites[parseInt(i)] will not be.

I suggest you change the ‘value’ attribute to “i” instead of orchardSite.code

Comment: Not quite...doing so gives me a similar error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined"

Comment: You may have to parseInt of course. Sorry I missed that

Comment: Also, just noticed that you have not capitalised the OrchardSites inside the if statement used. You may want to check that too. It’s just this.props.metadata.orchardSites instead of this.props.metadata.OrchardSites

Comment: parseInt where? on the value? and yeah I fixed the case sensitivity, didn't make a difference as the code wasn't even reaching that line

Comment: OrchardSites is an array. It can’t have “R1018A” as an index. Which is why you’re getting an undefined. Array indices are supposed to be whole numbers starting from 0. In your jsx, pass the “value” as “i” to the <option> tag. That way, in your function, you’ll have event.target.value as i, which is the correct array index. OrchardSite.code is never the correct index to use here. Fix this and the case sensitivity. It should work together. Else, share a code pen. Happy to help you debug further is this fails :)

Comment: I've changed the value as you suggested, from `<option value={orchardSites.code}> `to `<option value={i.toString()}>` ...blocks is still undefined unfortunately, the project I'm working on is quite big, lots of cogs in place so it will be quite hard to get a codepen running